# Generate multiplication table from a single for loop

Tags: c#, math

Is it possible to generate a multiplication table (for example, from 1 to 9) with a single `for` loop?

Comment: Yes you could. Is this a school project or something? We can't do your homework for you :)

Comment: You can even without a loop. You have to think of this yourself, it isn't that hard.

Comment: ya.. i just wanted to know that.. i don`t want the solution :) anyways.. thanks alot :)

Comment: `int multiplication_table[9][9] = {{1,2,3,...},{2,4,6,...},...};`. Not even code is required! :P

Comment: @Abid, why would you not just *try* it, before asking for verification?

Comment: @KevinP: apparently we *can*... =p

Comment: Indeed, as it is this simple. A real Try first, Ask later case.

Comment: thanks a lot :)) still trying my best :).. struggling :/

Comment: @kevin: We do help people with their homeworks/projects as long as they try 1st :)  @ Abid :  try , post your ideas, codes and you will find the people here more than willing to help ..

Comment: Yeah I know. Just joking around as the OP didn't even try it first :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using something like this... But why not using two nested loops?

> ```
>         for (int i = 0; i < 9 * 9; ++i)
>         {
>             int a = i / 9 + 1;
>             int b = i % 9 + 1;
>             Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", a, b, a * b);
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To generate the multiplication table of 1-9 with a single for loop you could loop 81 time and use the division and modulo operator to get the two operands.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9*9; ++i)
{
  int a = i / 9 + 1;
  int b = i % 9 + 1;
  Console.WriteLine($"{a} * {b} = {a * b}"); 
  //Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", a, b, a * b);
}
```

Note, there must be a better way to construct the output, but I'm not familiar with C#.

Comment: See sergioms answer for the proper way to do String formatting in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint for one way to do it.

How can you extract all of the needed multipliers and multiplicands from a single integer from 0 to 81?

Comment: Research the modulus operator, `%`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Console.WriteLine("     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9");

for (int i = 1; i<10; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(
      string.Format("{0}: {1:#0} {2:#0} {3:#0} {4:#0} " +
                    "{5:#0} {6:#0} {7:#0} {8:#0} {9:#0}",
          i, i, 2*i, 3*i, 4*i, 5*i, 6*i, 7*i, 8*i, 9*i));
```

Answer (score 0):

here, the code for multiplication tables based on our criteria
suppose 
Enter a value:2
Enter b value:10
then the output is like 2*1=2 to 2*10=20...

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b, c, d;
        Console.WriteLine("enter a value:");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("enter b value:");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (d = 1; d <=b; d++)
        {
            c = a * d;
          Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}",a,d,c);


        }
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
       Console.Write("Enter the value:");
       int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       if (m == 0)
           return;
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} ={2}",m,i,m*i);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication11    
{    
    class Program    
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c; 

        public void Accept()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter the no.:");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
            {
                b = a * c;
                Console.WriteLine("table: {0}", b);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void Display()
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(a "X" + c +"="b);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pr = new Program();
            pr.Accept();
            pr.Process();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is C solution, but you may easily re-write it into whatever language you like.

#include <stdio.h>

```
void Mult_table(int n)
{
  int i;
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  int count = 0;
  
  for (i= 0; i< n*n; ++i)
  {
    a = i/n + 1;
    b = i%n + 1;
    printf("%4d  ", a*b);
    count++;
    if(count %n == 0) /*new line*/
    {
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Output (if n = 10, but will work with any n):

1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30
4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40
5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50
6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60
7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70
8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80
9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90
10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100